# UWP ComboBox not showing Bound item

Tags: c#, combobox, win-universal-app

I have a Combobox containing a collection of Int32 Objects. The ComboBox SelectedItem is bound to an Int32.

```
            <ComboBox>
                <ComboBox.SelectedItem>
                    <Binding Path="MidiChannel" Mode="TwoWay" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" />
                </ComboBox.SelectedItem>
                <ComboBox.Items>
                <ComboBoxItem>
                    <x:Int32>0</x:Int32>
                </ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>
                    <x:Int32>1</x:Int32>
                </ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>
                    <x:Int32>2</x:Int32>
                </ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>
                    <x:Int32>3</x:Int32>
                </ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>
                    <x:Int32>4</x:Int32>
                </ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>
                    <x:Int32>5</x:Int32>
                </ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>
                    <x:Int32>6</x:Int32>
                </ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>
                    <x:Int32>7</x:Int32>
                </ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>
                    <x:Int32>8</x:Int32>
                </ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>
                    <x:Int32>9</x:Int32>
                </ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>
                    <x:Int32>10</x:Int32>
                </ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>
                    <x:Int32>11</x:Int32>
                </ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>
                    <x:Int32>12</x:Int32>
                </ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>
                    <x:Int32>13</x:Int32>
                </ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>
                    <x:Int32>14</x:Int32>
                </ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem>
                    <x:Int32>15</x:Int32>
                </ComboBoxItem>
                </ComboBox.Items>

            </ComboBox>
```

The MidiChannel property implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

Whatever combination I try, switching the collection and SelectedItem around, using SelectedValue instead of SelectedItem. The ComboBox won't show the SelectedItem in the UI. The output does not show any binding errors and I have checked that the Int32 is present in the class. How can I get the ComboBox to display my Int32?

Comment: Do post the MidiChannel property for completeness. Foir instance, is it an Int32?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure but you are filling your list with `<ComboboxItem>` elements. 
Your property should be of that type (better not) or your Path should reflect ComboboxItem.Content or something.

All in all it's much easier (better) to use the ItemSource property and let your ViewModel supply a list of integers. A simple array or `List<int>` is enough.

If you do want to use XAML for this, try omitting the wrapper:

```
  <ComboBox.Items>
    <x:Int32>0</x:Int32>
    <x:Int32>1</x:Int32>
    <x:Int32>2</x:Int32>
    ...
```